# how can I align three divs together and have one of them be disappear if the page size is of certain limit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

So I have three div with class as shown in the code snippet.

```css
/* CSS Question #4 */
        .box1 {
            background-color: green;
            width: 200px;
        }
        .box2 {
            background-color: grey;
            width: 200px;
        }
        .box3 {
            background-color: aqua;
            width: 200px;
        }
```

```html
<div>
              <h1>Arrage the div:</h1>
              <div>
                  <div class="box1">This one should be on the left side of the page</div>
                  <div class="box2">This one should be on the right side of the page</div>
                  <div class="box3">This one should be at the center of the page and it should disappear if the page become less than 800px.</div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

Im trying to make the box1 be on the left side, and make the box2 be on right side, and for box3 it needs to be in the middle and disappear if the page become less than 800px, as described in the divs themselves.

I have assigned float:left to box1 and float:right to box2 to have them each align to the left and right. But Im not sure about how I can get the box3 to be in the middle and disappear when the page is less than 800px.

Comment: Use a [CSS media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Answer (score 3):

I think, you should use media query. 
Here below is some reference link for media query.

```
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

http://learnlayout.com/media-queries.html
```

Above solution,

```
    .box1 {
            background-color: green;
            width: 50%;
            float:left;
          }
    .box2 {
             background-color: grey;
             width: 50%;
             float:right;
          }
    .box3 {
             background-color: aqua;
             width: 100%;
             clear:both;
          }
```

media query

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .box3 {
           display:none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Css all depends on what sizes you want the various boxes to be, personally I would set percentages to all three divs, say '33.33333333%' for the widths then write a media query that targets @media( max-width: 800px ) then set your middle div to display none and the left and right to 50% widths. This should give you the desired effect.

You should also move your third div to be in the second position or utilize flex to order them differently: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

```
          <div class="boxes">
              <div class="box1">This box should be on the left side of the page</div>
              <div class="spacer"></div>
              <div class="box3">This box should be at the center of the page and should disappear if the page is less than 800px.</div>
              <div class="spacer"></div>
              <div class="box2">This box should be on the right side of the page</div>
              <br/>
          </div>


    .boxes {display: flex;}

    .box1 {
        background-color: green;
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
    }
    .box2 {
        background-color: grey;
        width: 200px;
        float: right;
    }
    .box3 {
        background-color: aqua;
        width: 200px;
        flex: auto;
    }

    .spacer {flex-grow: 1}

    @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
        .box3 {
               display:none;
        }
    }
```

That's how I did it anyway...